# How much cost of using a style for gridview cell that used a converter in it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, radgridview, staticresource

I used a style for showing tooltip in a cell of telerik gridview (that converts numbers to words and shows in tooltip) like the below code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PaidAmountConverter" TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=PaidAmount, Converter={Infrastructure:PriceConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Top" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it in gridview like the below code:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Paid Amount" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PaidAmount, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" CellStyle="{StaticResource PaidAmountConverter}" />
```

my question is how this static resource works? is this style and its converter that used in it, created on time and used for all gridview rows or not?
is this way have performance issue?

if yes, then what is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a single converter object and a single style object. These are resources.

The Grid uses these resources. Even if the bindings were dynamic resources instead of Static resources there would still be just these two objects; static and dynamic refers to how the binding works, not to the life time of the objects.

Make sure the converter code is fast.

For the rest: if you doubt the speed: test.